# Cannot send Image data type from web service

Tags: windows-phone-7

I use this lines of code in web service to send data:

```
 byte[] bajtat = (byte[])dr["Logo"];
                            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bajtat, 0, bajtat.Length);
                            ms.Write(bajtat, 0, bajtat.Length);
                            Image img = Image.FromStream(ms, true);


                            var partite = new Partite
                            {
                                EmriPartite = dr.GetString(2),
                                /*
                                 *   SqlDataReader.GetString - gets the value of the specified column as a string
                                 */
                                NrPartive = dr.GetInt32(1),
                                Akronimi = dr.GetString(4),
                                Foto = img
                            };
```

and it shows me error:

System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error generating the XML document. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type System.Drawing.Bitmap was not expected. Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not known statically.
   at

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any problem in sending image data as byte[] from WebService using WCF technology. You can use [DataMember] byte[]  for you DataContract class. Read the image data completely to byte[] field. And send using WCF service.

At the receiving part in WP7, you can have

```
 
    < Image Source={Binding MyImageSource} />
Where MyImageSource is a BitmapSource Type.
    And you can set its instance .SetSource(new MemoryStream(buffer, 0, buffer.Length));
Where buffer is the byte[].
```

Comment: 123 Developer i don't know how to create your answer i make this code:

byte[] buffer=value as byte[];
BitmapSource MyImageSource; // i cannot make =new BitmapSource()
MyImageSource.SetSource(new MemoryStream(buffer,0,buffer.Length);